# Integer concatenation c

Tags: c

I'm trying to concatenate two uint32_t and get back a uint64_t. Here's my method

```
uint64_t concat_int1_int2 (uint32_t int1, uint32_t int2) {
  uint64_t concatenated = int1;
  return concatenated << 32 | int2;
}
```

This seems to be extremely slow (I need to do it ~1,000,000 times and it is taking ~ 6 minutes). Two questions, why does the bit shift take so long (that seems to be the limiting step), and does anyone have a suggestion for a faster way to do this?

Comment: My first guess would be that you're compiling a 32-bit binary, and the compiler can't use a native "long" type. Doublecheck that your build produces an x64 executable?

Comment: As David said, this is the right way - what hardware are you using - is it 32bit by chance?

Comment: Can we see the calling code, or the output of some profiling program? If you're doing something like `for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) printf("%" PRIu64, concat_int1_int2(int1, int2));` then I can tell you why it's taking 6 minutes...

Comment: Also, it might be clearer if, instead of `int1` and `int2`, you named them, say, `high` and `low`.

Comment: I am running on a 64bit machine. Commented on David's answer as to why I thought the shift was the limiting step. Any comments on whether my line of thought is valid or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are doing it is correct. It may help to `inline` the function. Most likely your performance problem is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Hmmm...I was basing my belief that it was the bit shift that was the limiting step on the fact that if I simply took it out and just did computed concatenated OR int2 that my program executed quite quickly.

Comment: You're right. It was because of code I wasn't showing. The uint64_t that I was computed was being used as the key for a GHashTable. It was important to have both ints in the key. For some reason doing this

  uint64_t concat_int1_int2 (uint32_t int1, uint32_t int2) {
    uint64_t concatenated = int2;
    return concatenated << 32 | int1;
  }

solves the performance issue. Anyone know anything about how the GHashTable is built and why this would be the case?

Comment: A simple shift and OR is too naive a mixing function for a hash key. It will work sometimes (if the input has the right characteristics) and fail in other cases (if it does not). Try: `uint64_t key=int2; key*=2654435761U; return key^int1;` (Thank you, Knuth!)

Comment: Let me clarify, this wasn't for the mixing function, just for creating unique keys that were being inserted into the hash table.

Comment: Ahh, then the problem is likely that your table requires the keys to be evenly distributed. You can solve it by switching to a table that doesn't have this requirement or by 'mixing' your keys so that they are more evenly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is near optiomal, it can't be much faster. Marking the function as `inline` may help a very little, but will not make much difference.
I made a test here in my machine using your code, it took 10ms to run 1,000,000 iterations of it. Your speed problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Why bitshift? Just shovel the 32 bit ints into the appropriate memory locations. Something like:

```
 *((uint32_t*) concatenated) = int1;
 *(((uint32_t*) concatenated)+1) = int2;
```

Now that I've given you that idea, note that in this function, int1 and int2 are ALREADY next to each other on the stack. So if they're in the right order, merely casting one of the parameters to a uint64_t does what you want! Yay pointers!

Comment: The problem is that which memory location is "appropriate" depends on details of the hardware. Worse, this *forces* operations to take place in memory while his code can take place entirely in registers, so it's likely to perform worse.

Comment: I don't think it depends on the hardware. Assuming the normal C calling convention the arguments are always pushed onto the stack right to left... they have to be for printf() et al to work, so this doesn't vary from architecture to architecture. As to how it performs, you'd have to test it.

Comment: Why make it look hackier than it has to? `((uint32_t *)concatenated)[0] = int1; ((uint32_t *)concatenated)[1] = int2;` (This approach can even help with the endianness issue - change `0` and `1` to `HIGH` and `LOW`, which are `#define`d appropriately for the target system's endianness.

Comment: You kids with your newfangled "arrays".

Comment: On ARM and other RISC architectures, arguments are usually passed via registers, not via stack. Even a x86 compiler can be configured to generated code that pass the parameters via registers (`-mregparm` switch in GCC). A program should make no such assumptions and make the cast as you suggest. Anyway, casting the value would not do, the compiler would guarantee the semantic equivalence of the numbers, padding the extra bytes with zeroes. For this hack to work, the address of the parameter must be cast to a `(uint64_t*)`, not the value itself.

Comment: The standard x86-64 calling convention even passes the first several arguments in registers, so it's really not that exotic at all.  If you take a pointer to those arguments the compiler will have to spill them to the stack, but the order in which that happens is certainly up to the compiler.